# Generic instantiating of childClass c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I want to create a object of a type which is derived from another type inside a generic Method.

What i try:

```
public static T Param<T>(this SomeClass foo) 
   where T : AbstractBaseClass, new() 
{       
   AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass bar =(AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass) new T();
   return (T) bar;
}
```

Objects of type T can be derived Objects either of AbstractBaseClass or of AbstractClassDerievedFromBaseClass.

The Question is: How to instantiiate a object of a DerivedType.

I already tried to check if the type is correct:

```
AbstractBaseClass abc = new T();
if(abc is AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass)
   AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass acdfbc = new T();
```

But i also get the compile Error:

> Cannot convert type 'T' to AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to cast to `AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass` to get that to compile

Comment: Also tried `AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass acdfbc = (AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass) new T();` but that ends in a compile Error as well

Comment: Why you can't simple `return new T()`?

Comment: What is the point of casting `T` to `AbstractClassDerivedFromBaseClass` and then casting it back to `T`? **Casting does not change the object**, it only affects the type of a variable.

Comment: I think you're right. The method grew in history... I try to simplify it first and then look why this construct was build in first place. Thanks for the help!